# What other file types can you unzip?

Tags: windows, zip

I recently discovered that you can rename an .msg email file to .zip and then extract it to view it's contents.

[image: rename .msg to .zip]

[image: test.zip unzipped]

This brought me to wonder, what other file types can you unzip?

A quick Google search returned nothing.

This is more of a random just for fun question, If this is the wrong place to post it I apologise.

Comment: if viewing the file in Notepad+++ shows MZ as the 1st two characters, it will be in a MS ZIP format.   I add link to SENTO folder to include itself "SendTo" then use that to add app links like Notepad+++, so any file can easily be opened in raw data format without adding associations to otherwise non-viewable file contents.

Comment: Typically any program that uses [.zip compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)) can be opened by WinZip.

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question. Please read [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Asking for lists of things is off-topic.

Comment: First bytes of file as "PK" are most likely to be .zip file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many files that are secretly zips!

- MSG, DOCX, XLSX, PPTX, VSDX  - Microsoft Office Formats
- XPI & CRX - Chrome and Firefox extensions
- JAR - Java Archive File
- APK - Android Appliation
- ODT,ODS,ODP - Open Document Formats
- XPS - XML Paper Specification (Like a PDF)

Loads of files open in 7-zip. Even some installer EXEs.

You should setup the following context menu to easily enable you to open files as archives:

[image: Context Menu]

To do this:

1. Open 7-Zip
2. Go to Tools-> Options
3. Select the 7-Zip Tab
4. Tick Open Archive
5. Click OK

[image: Options]

You can also click the 'info' button in 7-Zip to see what file type it is.

[image: Info]

[image: Zip]

Comment: Wow thanks for this answer, great to learn about that Context menu with 7-zip!

Answer (score 0):

Office documents ending in `x` like .docx or .xlsx are renamed zip files too.

Comment: Voted the answer up. No reason this answer should have negative votes, although I would choose to not answer the question at all, given that its off-topic for SuperUser.

Answer (score 0):

.apk files for Android and .ipa files for iOS can be unzipped after changing the extensions to .zip